# Type mismatch. Required: (PaddingValues) → Unit Found: Unit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to display a profile screen using:

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        DarkTopBar()
    },
    content = ProfileContent()
)
```

Where the `ProfileContent()` looks like this:

```
@Composable
fun ProfileContent() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(top = 96.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Good day!",
            fontSize = 48.sp
        )
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but (PaddingValues) -> Unit was expected

What I have tried to solve this problem is to move the above function call inside the body:

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        DarkTopBar()
    }
) {
    ProfileContent() //Moved here.
}
```

But Android Studio is complaining saying:

> Content padding parameter it is not used

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is this a warning or an error? "But Android Studio is complaining saying:

Content padding parameter it is not used"

Comment: @Abhimanyu As I see, the app compiles, but why do I get this message? How can I overcome that?

Comment: "but do I get this message" can you explain where you are seeing this and if it is a warning or error.

Comment: @Abhimanyu Check [this](https://i.ibb.co/khWzc9y/1.png) out.

Comment: As the screenshot shows, it is a warning. If you have a value that you are not using, Android studio shows a warning. In this case, `Scaffold`'s `content` gives a `PaddingValue` and you are not using that. Hence the warning. You can ignore it unless you want to use the value.

Comment: @Abhimanyu Is there a way I can supress that warning? Thanks for taking the time to comment to my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244178/discussion-between-abhimanyu-and-joan-p).

Comment: You can pass modifier, which is also recommended, in your ProfileContent() and use Scaffold's paddingValues as padding in this modifier. Like: `Scaffold( topBar = { DarkTopBar() } ) { ProfileContent(modifier = Modifier.padding(it)) }` **Or,** you can just ignore the message from Android Studio (which is not recommended) adding **@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")**

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that the `content` parameter of `Scaffold` should take a composable function. Here, you are not passing the function as an argument as you think you are, but instead actually calling the function. To fix put the function call inside a lambda for `content` like you did for `topAppBar`.

So change this:

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        DarkTopBar()
    },
    content = ProfileContent()
)
```

To this:

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        DarkTopBar()
    },
    content = {
        ProfileContent()
    }
)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I get the exact same behaviour. Have you tried it? Please also note that I have the latest dependencies. Thanks anyway.